# не появляется фильтр в gridview в Yii2

Tags: yii2

Не понятно пытаюсь вывести фильтр (поиск) в gridview, не выводится.

```
public function actionIndex() {

    $model = new PackagesForm();
    $certificates = Certificate::find()->where(['certificates.user_id' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id,
        'package_id'=>null]);
    $packages = Packages::find()->where(['packages.user_id' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id]);
    $searchModel = new OfferSearch();
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $packages,
        'sort' => [
            'defaultOrder' => ['id' => SORT_DESC,'company' => SORT_DESC],
        ], 'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 10,
        ],
    ]);
    $dataCertificate = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $certificates,
        'sort' => [
            'defaultOrder' => ['id' => SORT_DESC],
        ], 'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 100,
        ],
```

`

```
 <?php
                echo GridView::widget([
                    'dataProvider' => $dataCertificate,
                    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
                    'columns' => [
                            [
                            'attribute' => 'certificate_code',
                            'label' => Yii::t('frontend', 'Code of certificate'),
                                  'filter'=>array("1"=>"Активно","2"=>"Не активно"),
                                ],

                            [
                            'attribute' => 'club_id',
                            'label' => Yii::t('frontend', 'Club'),
                            'value' => function ($data) {

                                $club = common\models\Club::findOne($data->club_id);
                                return $club->name;
                            },
                        ],
                            [
                            'attribute' => 'country_id',
                            'label' => Yii::t('frontend', 'Country'),
                            'value' => function ($data) {

                                $country = common\models\Country::findOne($data->country_id);
                                return $country->name;
                            }
                        ],
                            ['label' => Yii::t('frontend', 'Certificate costs'),
                            'attribute' => 'certificate_sum',],
                            [
                            'label' => Yii::t('frontend', 'Currency'),
                            'attribute' => 'certificate_currency',
                        ],
                            ['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn',
                            'name' => 'certificates',
                            'checkboxOptions' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
                                return ['value' => trim($model->certificate_code)];
                            }
                        ],
                    ],
                ]);
                ?>
```

Comment: **OfferSearch** покажите

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо  нужно было правильно OfferSearch написать

Answer (score 0):

По-моему у вас разные типы

`$dataCertificate` представляет выборку по типу `Certificate`
a
модель фильтра `$searchModel` имеет тип `OfferSearch`

Попробуйте представить переменную `$searchModel` к типу `Certificate` или если есть у вас класс для поиска `CertificateSearch`

Answer (score 0):

В **Search** моделе посмотрите на **rules**, функция должна возвращать необходимые колонки с правилами валидации...

```
 /**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [          
        [['name', 'slug'], 'string'],
    ];
}
```